# SQL: Group By only a part of the table in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to use SQL in Access to get a query where:
1) I filter out the fruits which have no sales.
2) I sum the sales for the different fruits and show the result on every line.

**Start:**
[image: Start]

**Result:**
[image: End Result]

I used the code below but it's not close to what I want as I also want the fruit N° which have no sales for the Fruit which have sales.

```
SELECT MySheet.Fruit, MySheet.[Fruit N°], SUM(Sales)
FROM MySheet
GROUP BY Fruit, [Fruit N°]
HAVING SUM(Sales) > 0;
```

Any Idea how to correct my code to get to my two points 1) and 2)?

Comment: Which version of Access?

Comment: @MatBailie Access 2016 64bits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
  MySheet.Fruit, MySheet.[Fruit N°], summary.totalSales
FROM
  MySheet
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT Fruit, SUM(Sales)  AS totalSales
  FROM MySheet
  GROUP BY Fruit
)
  summary
    ON summary.Fruit = MySheet.Fruit
WHERE
  summary.totalSales > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `subquery` :

```
SELECT S.Fruit, S.[Fruit N°], 
       (SELECT SUM(Sales) 
        FROM MySheet S1
        WHERE S1.Fruit = S.Fruit
       ) TotalSales
FROM MySheet S
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM MySheet 
              WHERE Fruit = S.Fruit 
              HAVING SUM(Sales) > 0
             );
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a subquery to do the grouping for you:

```
SELECT
  MySheet.Fruit,
  MySheet.[Fruit N°],
  s.FruitSales
FROM MySheet m
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    Fruit,
    SUM(Sales) AS FruitSales
  FROM MySheet
  GROUP BY Fruit
  HAVING SUM(Sales) > 0
  ) s
ON m.Fruit = s.Fruit
```